Returning arithmetic progressions from Vector in Julia
I am new to Julia, and currently stuck on extracting arithmetic progressions from a Vector{Int64} in Julia. Suppose I have a Vector like [1, 4, 5, 3, 9, 21, 16, 2, 22, 54, 17, 23], and I want to extract all consecutive sequences of length three or more. So, from the above, I want to get [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and [21, 22, 23] as separate vectors. What's the most efficient way to do this (Preferably without iteration for large vectors)?
I've tried using iteration to store and sequentially compare numbers but the memory usage is higher than I would like.

I'm not sure this can be done without any sort of iteration. How would you do it on paper?

Not strictly iteration free, but why not just sort and then do a single pass through the vector?

The code below actually makes 3 passes through the data: once for sorting, once for creating a diff the size of your vector, and once to create the found  sequences. It does minimize other allocations, so it should work with 32-bit integer vector sizes up to at least several hundred megabytes.
const vint = [1, 4, 5, 3, 9, 21, 16, 2, 22, 54, 17, 23]

function parse_sequences(vec, minimumlength)
    a = sort(vec)
    deltas = diff(a)
    pushfirst!(deltas, 0) # sync arrays
    sequences = Vector{Int}[]
    start = 1
    for i in eachindex(a)
        if deltas[i] != 1
            i - start >= minimumlength && push!(sequences, a[start:i-1])
            start = i
        end
    end
    return sequences
end

parse_sequences(vint, 3)

Or, for no allocations but the return values, you can use sort! to modify your original array in-place:
function parse_sequences(a, minimumlength)
    sort!(a)
    sequences = Vector{Int}[]
    start = 1
    for i in 2:lastindex(a)
        if a[i] - a[i-1] != 1
            i - start >= minimumlength && push!(sequences, a[start:i-1])
            start = i
        end
    end
    return sequences
end

